# Correcting a macro to select every nth column, instead of row

Tags: excel, vba

Please help to edit this code to work on Columns instead of Rows. I tried search and replace within the VBA "Row"->"Column", but the code only selects the first column. Below is the original code. Thanks

```
Sub EveryOtherRow()
Dim rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range
Dim OutRng As Range
Dim xInterval As Integer
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
xInterval = Application.InputBox("Enter row interval", xTitleId, Type:=1)
For i = 1 To InputRng.Rows.Count Step xInterval + 1
Set rng = InputRng.Cells(i, 1)
If OutRng Is Nothing Then
    Set OutRng = rng
Else
    Set OutRng = Application.Union(OutRng, rng)
End If
Next
OutRng.EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```vb
Sub EveryOtherColumn()
Dim rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range
Dim OutRng As Range
Dim xInterval As Long, i As Long
Dim xTitleId As String
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
xInterval = Application.InputBox("Enter row interval", xTitleId, Type:=1)
For i = 1 To InputRng.Columns.Count Step xInterval + 1
Set rng = InputRng.Cells(1, i)
If OutRng Is Nothing Then
    Set OutRng = rng
Else
    Set OutRng = Application.Union(OutRng, rng)
End If
Next
OutRng.EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen Thanks! You are right! I edited the code, also declared `i`.

Comment: I see what you did there, thanks. So (1, i) represents columns and rows, right?

Comment: @PavloKobzar `Cells` takes two parameters, the first represents the rows, the second the columns (think of it as a matrix). Also loop over `InputRng.Columns.Count` instead of `InputRng.Rows.Count`